# Creating repeating list 0,0,1,1,2,2

Tags: list

I'm trying to create a list of 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4. It's in natural sequence but each of the number can get repeated 2 times or n times, but I'm not sure how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in a particular language?  Is `n` constant or variable for each number in the list?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Im looking for an answer in c#. Im sorry Im new to stackoverflow too

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
N=4 'upper Limit
R=2 'Number of repetitions in the sequence.
for i = 0 to N
   for j = 1 to R
     print i
   next j
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function iterateList(startIndex, limit) {
    var arr = [];

    while (startIndex < limit) {
      arr.push(startIndex, startIndex);
      startIndex++;
    }

    return arr;
  }

  console.log(iterateList(0, 10));

});
```